# Validity of these pointers

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am currently trying to improve my grasp on pointers and ARC. 
Consider the following example

```
@implementation Foobar

-(NSArray *)methodA {
    return self.someArray;
}

-(NSArray *)methodB {
    return [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

@end
```

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property(strong) NSArray * myArrayA;
@property(strong) NSArray * myArrayB;
@end

@implementation Foo

-(void)fooMethod {
    //suppose f is an instance of foobar
    self.myArrayA = [f methodA];  //---->statement 1
    self.myArrayB = [f methodB];  //---->statement 2
    //Destructor of f instance is called.
    //Will myArrayA and myArrayB be valid ?
}

@end
```

Now in `fooMethod` the class `foo` has two strong properties of Arrays `myArrayA` and `myArrayB` now `myArrayA` is referencing a strong pointer from the class instance `foobar` however `myArrayB` is referencing a strong pointer which is created in a scope . Now suppose that  somehow the destrcutor of instance f is called. When that destrcutor is called it will clear the contents of of `SomeArray` thus invalidating `myArrayA` however since its destructor is not aware of the memory allocated by `MethodB` that memory will still be alive. My understanding is that if the instance f is destroyed after statement 2 the address pointed to by myArrayA will be invalid whereas the address pointed to by myArrayB will be valid. Kindly let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: There is no such thing as a destructor in Objective-C. If your instance of 'f' is created in fooMethod, you are guaranteed a strong reference to it until the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, the method that is called when an object ceases to exist is called `dealloc`, and we tend to refer to it simply as that, `dealloc`, and don't call it the "destructor", although `dealloc` is pretty close to the equivalent of other language's destructor.

However, with that said, ARC forbids you from directly calling `dealloc` on an object.  If you are calling `dealloc` on an object directly, your project will not compile if you are using ARC.

Instead, ARC writes in your memory management code.  At some point after an object has zero remaining strong references (it is not guaranteed to happen immediately), ARC will deallocate your object.  But importantly, an object can have *any number* of strong references to it.  So, let's take a look at your specific example.

`f`, in your example, is an already instantiated instance of class `Foobar` which has a property `someArray`.  You fail to show how the property is declared, but let's assume it's declared the same way the properties in `Foo` are declared (as `strong`).  At whatever point the `someArray` property becomes non-nil, there is at least one strong reference to that array.

For the sake of argument, let's assume that `f` is the only strong reference to this array.  This will make the array's reference count equal to one.

Now, in `Foo`, we set `myArrayA` to `f`'s `someArray` property.  This array now has two strong references--a reference count equal to two.

Meanwhile, `Foo`'s `myArrayB` is set equal to a newly instantiated `NSArray` object.  `f` doesn't keep a strong reference to this array.  As soon as `methodB` returns, only the `Foo` class's `myArrayB` has a strong reference to the array.  It has a reference count equal to one.

Now, let's say we keep `f` around (through whatever means), but our `Foo` instance is deallocated (however), what happens to the two arrays?

Because our instance of `Foo` is deallocated, it will no longer hold a strong reference to either array.  ARC will decrement each array's reference count by one.

`Foo`'s `myArrayA` will have its reference count decremented from two to one--`f` still holds a strong reference, and the array is not deallocated.

`Foo`'s `myArrayB` will have its reference count decremented from one to zero--nothing else holds a strong reference to `myArrayB`, so with a reference count of zero, ARC will deallocate this array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `f` is an instance of `foobar`, when you call `[f MethodA]` (and method names should be named `likeThis`), it will return `self.SomeArray;`. `self.myArrayA` will hold a strong pointer to the array returned, regardless of f's status (if its `dealloc`ed or not).

Equally, `[f MethodB]` returns `[[NSArray alloc]init]`, so `self.myArrayB` will hold a strong pointer to that instance that you just created, and it will be held until you set `self.myArrayB` to nil.